# variable declaration in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, instance-variables

Whats the difference between variable declared in interface (in ".h" file) and in implementation in (in .m file)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data declared inside the brackets in an @interface { ... } ... @end block is an instance variable of the class.   Data declared (at global scope) inside a .m file is app-global data.     There is nothing magic about .h versus .m files, .h files are just usually #import'ed into .m files.  The important thing is whether the data is insdide an @interface { ... } ... @end.   So too, data in a .h file declared outside of @interface will be at app global scope.

Comment: ohhhhhh thanks man!!!!
i declare some variable "x" in "classA.m" and have few instance of th "classA" whenever any of its object get released app crashes as all the obj uses x. when i moved x to ".h" everything is fine

Comment: That should be "ClassA.m" and "ClassA";  classes start with capital letters.